# Turn off certain hlint rules in vscode

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I have the following Visual Studio Code extensions for Haskell installed:

[image]

If I use `elem` in a prefix form:

```
(elem n primes)
```

I get a blue squiggly that suggests the infix form:

[image]

Is there a way to turn off just this particular hlint rule, `hlint(refact:Use infix)` just for this file or project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes!

For a single source file, add one of these to the top of the file:

```
{-# ANN module "HLint: ignore Use infix" #-}

{-# HLINT ignore "Use infix" #-}

{- HLINT ignore "Use infix" -}
```

For the entire project, create a file `.hlint.yaml` as follows:

```
- ignore: {name: Use infix}
```

You can also run `hlint --default > .hlint.yaml` from a terminal, which will create a `.hlint.yaml` file ignoring any hints currently uncorrected in your project.

These are not VS Code specific - they apply wherever `hlint` is used.

For more information see the [HLint manual](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/blob/master/README.md#ignoring-hints).

Happy Haskelling!

Comment: Thanks Ari! I had seen the manual but was getting errors when I used the above. However, your answer prompted me to reread the manual and try again. I had been putting the pragmas *before* the `module` line, and this wasn't working. I added them after the `module` line and it's working great.

Comment: None of the recommended comment formats work for me.